# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, classpath

I have some unit tests that load an application context from an XML file:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-application-context.xml");

}
```

This throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [test-application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test-application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

My unit test class is in the folder:

myproj/myproj-configuration-dal/src/test/java/com/mypatterns/api/data/impl/LogTest.java

The resource file is in:

myproj/myproj-configuration-dal/src/test/resources/test-application-context.xml

I tried moving the xml file around and, also the entire resouce folder, to the following locations: the src folder, the folder where LogTest is, to the main folder (where the non-test sources are) and so on.

Where exactly is this supposed to be? Where is ClassPathXmlApplicationContext looking for the resources?

Thanks,
Serban

Comment: I believe you are missing a trailing slash, `/test-application-context.xml`.

Comment: I tried adding one, didn't work. When you write like this: "/test-application-context.xml", it means that this is an absolute path, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that replacing `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` with `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` makes the job much easier. You can use this one and you won't have this problem.